# Teams Bot Acquire Using

Tags: botframework, office-js, microsoft-teams

I'm wondering if anybody knows what does `Acquire Using` stands for and how it can be changed in Teams Bot manifest or any other places? If I understand it correctly Teams app can be used with both personal and business accounts. So it looks like `Acquire Using` limits usage to only business account but I don't see anything about that in the manifest documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema. I also found that mostly all apps in the store requires `Work or school account`, e.g. [Stackoverflow app](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000739) but I found couple apps which also allow `Microsoft account`, e.g. [Salesforce app](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379334?tab=Overview). Does `Microsoft account` stands for personal? How can I change the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question in [Microsoft BotBuilred repository](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2483).

If I got it right this field is set by certification team and by design all Team applications requires Business or School account. Salesforce in the first post belongs to Outlook applications which is different class of applications and it's possible to choose who can use it.
So in a nutshell it's kind of business decision to limit all Teams applications only to business or school account. Also if got it right again it's not kind of documented limitation but just an internal rule.